# Can't issue one item at a time, everytime i issue an item it always issued all items left instead of one item only

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to issue an item here(i have 2 stock item left) but it seems like every time I issue an item all 2 stock item is getting issued instead of 1 stock item only.

Here's the issuance of the item code below:

```
String sql = "insert into issueditem(Item_No,Item ID, Item Name, Issued Date, "
       + "Due Date,  Item Number, Stock) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

try {     
    connect()
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txtitemno.getText());
    pst.setString(2, itemid.getText());
    pst.setString(3, itemname.getText());
    pst.setString(4, txtidate.getText());
    pst.setString(5, txtredate.getText());
    pst.setString(6, itemnum.getText());
    pst.setString(7, stock.getText());

    pst.execute();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item issued");
    update();

} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Here's the update method every time I Issue an item:

```
public void update(){ 
    int st = Integer.parseInt(stock.getText()); 
    int q = 1;
    int sup = st - q ;
    stock.setText(sup+"");
    try {
        String val1= jbd.getText();
        String val2 = jt88.getText();
        String val3=jt14.getText();
        if (sup>=0 && val2.equals("0")){
            String sql =  "update storageitem set Available = 'NO',  Stock= '"+val2+"'"
            + " where ItemID='"+val1+"' ";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item is not issued");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you know that 2 items are issued?

Comment: I checked my mysql database it went from 2 stocks left to 0 stocks left after i issued  an item.

Comment: Coz i think in my issue form i have a textfield for stocks quantity left which is 2 stocks left then when i issued an item that stocks quantity left are getting issued instead of 1.

Comment: The "item is issued" and "Item is not issued" pop up at the same time after i click the issue button and the quantity stocks left all got issued instead of 1 item only and the stock item left textfield reduced to 1